# CSS error with position and overflow on all browsers

Tags: css, position, overflow

I have set up a scrollable `div` that until recently was scrolling and now appears to be jammed at the top. The only difference is the addition of `position: relative;`.

Here is a FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/PMzcB/

Any ideas why?

Comment: "error ... on all browsers" generally means "error with my code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change z-index to a positive value.

Comment: I would have earlier but had to wait 7 mins

Answer (score 0):

The `z-index:-1;` was the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/PMzcB/13/